# How to send input to all splits in Byobu?

Tags: byobu

What is the equivalent tmux command `:setw synchronize-panes` in byobu? Byobu has <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> to run a command in all splits, but this does not help if I want to, say, edit the same file using vim in two splits connected to two different remote hosts.

If this feature is missing in byobu can this be added or can this be added by customizing byobu?

Comment: Nope, does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> , this will the toggle tmux's option `synchronize-panes`

This functionality is available by default since version 5.87 - https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/pull/4

Source: http://fazlearefin.blogspot.com.au/2014/09/synchronize-panes-in-tmux-and-byobu.html

Comment: Please summarize the information in your link and include it in your answer. Otherwise, this answer is coupled to that link, which may change (or rot) over time. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers